# How do you sort a JavaScript array that includes NaNs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, nan

I'm trying to sort an array that sometimes has `Infinity` or `NaN`. When I use a standard JavaScript `array.sort()` it seems to sort until it reaches a `NaN` and then I get random results after that.

```
var array =[.02,.2,-.2,Nan,Infinity,20];
```

Is there a way to still sort this so that the end result is from negative to positive and still have `NaN` or `Infinity` at the end.

```
-.2,.02,.2,20,NaN,Infinity
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of the array?

Comment: Will adjusting the logic in the function to deal with the NaN special case work? Some sort of if(isNaN(a)) { return positive } // so it's always at one end

Comment: @loosebazooka 's comment is the answer to the question

Comment: Oops, I forgot a number ordering... fixed the answer.

Comment: @loosebazooka, but for the sake of sorting, NaN should equal NaN (even though `NaN !== NaN` in JS)

Comment: @daniel savage, I would say it is because it is unclear what you are expecting as a result, your question is vague and not well defined.

Comment: @daniel savage, now that you have clarified a little more, this renders my answer incorrect (and some others too) and I will be removing it. It is still unknown whether you will ever have `-Infinity`, and if yes, in what order it should appear.

Comment: Upvoting this back to zero, since this question is now sufficiently clear. (What's the point in downvoting a question if you don't upvote again when the problem is fixed?) @HoboSapiens: Trying to invalidate the question is poor form. Just because an operation is mathematically undefined doesn't mean it has to be algorithmically undefined. Languages and libraries designed more thoughtfully than Javascript, such as NumPy, handle this issue with grace; the fact that Javascript doesn't is a design bug, IMHO.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note: this solution has problems with some edge-cases and seems to be not fully browser independent, [please refer to the answer by Esailija](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17558191/2422125) or the modern one from [trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56265258/2422125)

---

You can catch `NaN` and `Infinity` using JavaScript's built-in utility functions for those cases:

```js
//sort -Infinity, NaN, Infinity to the end in random order
func = function(a,b){
  if(isFinite(a-b)) {
    return a-b; 
  } else {
    return isFinite(a) ? -1 : 1;
  }
};

//[-1,-1,0,0,1,2,5,6,10,NaN,Infinity,Infinity,NaN,-Infinity,NaN]
console.log(...[Infinity, -1, 6, 1, 0, NaN, 0, -1, 2, 5, 10, -Infinity, NaN, Infinity, NaN].sort(func))
// fails for edge case
console.log(...[-Number.MAX_VALUE, Number.MAX_VALUE].sort(func))
console.log(...[Number.MAX_VALUE, -Number.MAX_VALUE].sort(func))




//sort -Infinity<0<Infinity<NaN
func = function(a,b){
  if(isNaN(a)) { 
    return isNaN(b) ? 1 : b;
  } else {
    return isNaN(b) ? -1 : a-b; 
  }
}

//[-Infinity,-1,-1,0,0,1,2,5,6,10,Infinity,Infinity,NaN,NaN,NaN]
console.log(...[Infinity, -1, 6, 1, 0, NaN, 0, -1, 2, 5, 10, -Infinity, NaN, Infinity, NaN].sort(func))
console.log(...[-Number.MAX_VALUE, Number.MAX_VALUE].sort(func))
console.log(...[Number.MAX_VALUE, -Number.MAX_VALUE].sort(func))
```

Comment: Parenthesis at the end is missing. Seems to work now for my test case.

Comment: It is still essentially shuffling the array. Also, `isFinite` already checks for `NaN`

Comment: It's hard to comprehend how this can get accepted as an answer when it is clearly broken. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/T6Lj8/) -> `[2, NaN, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 5, 10, -Infinity, NaN, NaN, Infinity]`

Comment: Your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/T6Lj8/1 gives as result `-1,-1,0,0,0,1,2,5,10,NaN,NaN,NaN,Infinity,-Infinity` Where is the problem ? 
(Tested with Firefox and Opera) ah and fails with Chrome ... -.-

Comment: In both Chromium v25 and Google Chrome v28 it shows `[2, NaN, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 5, 10, -Infinity, NaN, NaN, Infinity] `

Comment: array.sort() working differently in chrome and firefox and ie
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832158/array-sort-working-differently-in-chrome-and-firefox-and-ie ... I fixed the problem 
(http://jsfiddle.net/T6Lj8/2/ Tested with Firefox, Opera, Chrom)

Comment: Chromium uses an unstable sort (not sure which method) whereas FireFox uses a [stable sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability) (a merge-sort I believe). [ECMA-262](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11) does not specify which type of sort must be used and rather leaves it up to the vendor to choose.

Comment: @Xotic750 To make it more confusing V8/Chrome/Chromium uses Insertion Sort (Stable) for arrays with <= 22 items and Quicksort (Unstable) for arrays with more items :P

Comment: Cleaned up the code of the answer, tested to be still working in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Still broken, in Microsoft Edge Version 113, the array `[NaN,0]` gets sorted as `[NaN,0]`. Meanwhile in Firefox Version 113, it gets sorted as `[0, NaN]`.
The second compare function simply doesn't handle the case where `b` is NaN.

Comment: @Stefnotch you are right, i updated the script and tested it with edge, no idea how stable it is though.

Comment: @FabianN. I'm sorry to report that it's still a bit broken. The stack snippet no longer executes, and `array = [-1, NaN]` doesn't get sorted correctly  on Edge. `array = [NaN, -1]` doesn't get sorted on Firefox.

Comment: Oh, also, the first function returns the wrong result for the input `array = [Number.MAX_VALUE, -Number.MAX_VALUE]` on Firefox. It should equally break with the `array = [-Number.MAX_VALUE, Number.MAX_VALUE]` input on Chrome.

Comment: @Stefnotch sorry i accidentially broke the snipped, for the -Number.MAX_VALUE, Number.MAX_VALUE edgecase ... i'm out. Gonna be honest, I'm will edit the answer to refer to the solution of Esailija and trincot

Answer (score 15):

Negative infinity should logically be ordered first, as it is effectively smaller than all other numbers.

I would thus do it like this:

```js
const cmp = (a,b) => a-b || isNaN(a)-isNaN(b);

// Example
const arr = [Infinity, NaN, Infinity, -Infinity, NaN, 1, 0, NaN, -1, -0];
console.log(arr.sort(cmp));
```

Here -0 and 0 are considered equal and can appear in any relative order.

If you want to ensure that -0 gets ordered before 0, then:

```js
const cmp = (a,b) => a-b || isNaN(a)-isNaN(b) || Object.is(b, -0) - Object.is(a, -0);

// Example
const arr = [Infinity, NaN, Infinity, -Infinity, NaN, 1, 0, NaN, -1, -0];
console.log(arr.sort(cmp));
```

Note that Stack Snippets does not retain the `-0`... See browser console.

Comment: This is the best modern approach answer which also fixes a chrome issue I was having with Fabian's answer.

Comment: This answer includes a `-0` in its test case, and yet the test case fails on Firefox 113.
`[ -Infinity, -1, 0, -0, 1, Infinity, Infinity, NaN, NaN, NaN ]`

Comment: @Stefnotch, are you suggesting that -0 < 0?

Comment: I am indeed suggesting that if one defines a total order for doubles, then `-0` comes before `0`. Of course the question didn't ask for it, so I suppose it doesn't matter for the sake of this answer.

Comment: Alright, added an expanded version to my answer for enforcing that order.

Answer (score 14):

If you just want to bump them to the end in a random order:

```js
var arr = [-1, 0, 1, 10, NaN, 2, NaN, 0, -1, NaN, 5, Infinity, 0, -Infinity];

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (!isFinite(a) && !isFinite(b)) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (!isFinite(a)) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (!isFinite(b)) {
    return -1;
  }
  return a - b;
});

console.log(...arr)
//[-1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 10, NaN, NaN, NaN, Infinity, -Infinity]
```

If you want to also sort the infinities at the end:

```js
var arr = [-1, 0, 1, 10, NaN, 2, NaN, 0, -1, NaN, 5, Infinity, 0, -Infinity];

arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  if( !isFinite(a) && !isFinite(b) ) {
    return ( isNaN(a) && isNaN(b) )
        ? 1
        : a < b
            ? -1
            : a === b
                ? 0
                : 1;
  }
  if( !isFinite(a) ) {
      return 1;
  }
  if( !isFinite(b) ) {
      return -1;
  }
  return a-b;
});

//[-1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 10, -Infinity, Infinity, NaN, NaN, NaN]
console.log(...arr)
```

Here the order is `-Infinity` < `Infinity` < `NaN`

Comment: No need for all the `else if`s, otherwise +1

Comment: @Xotic750 how is there no need for the else ifs?

Comment: Because of the `return` if matched.

Comment: @Xotic750 well that is still essentially else if even if it is neater, I thought you were talking about getting rid of branching entirely or something.

Comment: @Xotic750 yeah fine, removed them now

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
var arr = [-1, 0, 1, 10, NaN, 2, NaN, 0, -1, NaN, 5, Infinity, 0];

function sortInf(a, b) {
  a = parseFloat(a);
  b = parseFloat(b);
  if ((!a || a === -Infinity) && a !== 0) {
    return 1;
  } else if ((!b || b === -Infinity) && b !== 0) {
    return -1;
  } else return a - b;
}
console.log(...arr.sort(sortInf));
```

Comment: Doesn't work with `[-1, 0, 1, 10, NaN, 2, NaN, 0, -1, NaN, 5, Infinity, 0, -Infinity]`

Comment: @Esailija Thanks for the info, I just didn't test it with all possible combinations, fixed the code...

Comment: Still doesn't appear sorted to me [jsfiddl](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/aL2Fy/) -> `[-1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 10, Infinity, NaN, -Infinity, NaN, NaN]`

Comment: @Xotic750 OP says "`NaN or Infinities at the end`", I understood the order of the Infinities and NaNs doesn't matter, just they appear at the end of the array. Please correct me if I'm wrong with this...

Comment: It could certainly be taken that way as the OP is unclear, though `sort` for me means of a particular ordering and I wouldn't expect to see `Infinity, NaN, -Infinity, NaN`. Though the latest update from the OP shows `-.2,.02,.2,20,NaN,Infinity`

Comment: @Xotic750 Well, I can understand your point of the view, order is an order, even a looser one ; ). Looks like OP isn't online anymore, so asking him won't help at the moment...

Comment: Such is the problem with poorly defined questions. I removed my answer after the last question update.

Answer (score -1):

a simple and fast way without conditional or function overhead:

```js
var r = [1, 9, NaN, 3, 4, 5, 0, -4, NaN, 4, Infinity, 7, 2];
r.sort(function(a, b, c) {return a - b || (a || Infinity) - (b || Infinity) || 0});
console.log(...r) // == -4,0,1,2,3,4,4,5,7,9,NaN,NaN,Infinity
```

EDIT: updated based on feedback to avoid a NaN return.

this executes about 20X faster than the other answers, so it's ideal if you need perf, and sorting is one area where perf often DOES matter...

Comment: This returns `NaN`s to the sort implementation

Comment: @Esailija: why is that bad? can you please elaborate? (it seems to work for me)

Comment: The custom function should return less than 0, 0, or more than 0. Returning NaN doesn't make any sense. If it works for one input in one browser then good for you. All the specifications says for this that the results for incorrect sort functions are implementation defined.

Comment: @Esailija: interesting. are there any browsers you know of where this causes a problem?

Comment: What is happening here though? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/9DcW8/) -> `-Infinity, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 10, NaN, NaN, NaN, Infinity] `

Comment: @Esailija: ahh, the old "your answer doesn't solve a different question than posed" routine. I never saw anything about -Infinity. in fact, i've never see -Infinity in the wild, but if handling it is worth a 20X slowdown, then you gotta do what you gotta do.

Comment: I don't see any backup for the 20X, for instance here it is actually slower in firefox http://jsperf.com/arrsarrs. If you need to sort things a lot as to worry about performance I would actually suggest using a different data structure like a binary search tree.

Comment: @Esailija:  the 20X i measured was on the data set in my answer. on the OP's data, your functions are only 2-3X slower in v8...

Comment: Still doesn't work even with `-Infinity` removed, [jsfidde](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/7kaYt/) - > `[-1, -1, NaN, 0, NaN, 0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 10, Infinity, NaN]`